# cdk: Importing the output of an unrelated different stack

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

Context: 
I am making a new stack using cdk. This stack will use a vpc id that is an Output from a different stack in the same account, one which is not generated by cdk.

I am looking for the cdk equivalent of

```
Fn::ImportValue: ExportedName
```

in order to create a VPC in cdk which can then have resources attached to it.

I will then use that output to look up the VPC:

```java
Vpc.fromVpcAttributes(this, "MyImportedVPC", VpcAttributes.builder()
    .withVpcId(importedValue).build());
```

All the references I can find to importing values with cdk are about importing (or rather, not having to manually import) values defined in a stack which is also created by cdk. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was looking for `Fn.importValue`:

```java
Fn.importValue("ExportedName")

List<String> availabilityZones = java.util.stream.Stream
        .of("us-west-2a", "us-west-2b", "us-west-2c")
        .collect(toList());

String privateSubnet1 = Fn.importValue("PrivateSubnet01");
String privateSubnet2 = Fn.importValue("PrivateSubnet02");
String privateSubnet3 = Fn.importValue("PrivateSubnet03");

List<String> privateSubnets = java.util.stream.Stream
        .of(privateSubnet1, privateSubnet2, privateSubnet3)
        .collect(toList());

VpcAttributes byId = VpcAttributes.builder()
        .withVpcId(vpcId)
        .withAvailabilityZones(availabilityZones)
        .withPrivateSubnetIds(privateSubnets)
        .build();

return Vpc.fromVpcAttributes(this, "ImportedVpc", byId);
```